# Strictly Positive Solution for Linear System

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am sorry but I feel completely stuck on the following problem. I have tried linear algebra techniques, but this got me nowhere so far. Any help would be appreciated.

The problem is as follows: given a set of vectors $\{ (\cos \theta_i, \sin \theta_i)\}_{i=1}^k\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $k\geq 3$  and they are not all contained in any of the open half-planes, we need to find strictly positive coefficients $a_i$ so that the sum of the vectors is zero. That is $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \cos \theta_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \sin \theta_i = 0$ with $a_i > 0$.

Comment: Did you really mean do say *open* half-plane? In this case, strictly positive coefficients cannot necessarily be found. Let $k=3.$ There is no open half plane that contains the points for $\theta_1=0,$ $\theta_2=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta_3=\pi,$ but necessarily $a_2=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Notice 
$$ 
\sum_k a_i (\cos \theta_i, \sin \theta_i) = 0 \iff 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos \theta_1 & \cos \theta_2 & \dots & \cos \theta_k\\ 
\sin \theta_1 & \sin \theta_2 & \dots & \sin \theta_k\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_k
\end{pmatrix} = 0 \iff \mathbf{T}\overline{a} = 0
$$

Now we're simply solving for the nullspace of $\mathbf{T}$, which I trust you can do.

Once we have a basis for the nullspace, we'll have vectors $\{ v_1 \ldots v_r \}$ so that every $\overline{a}$ which satisfies $\mathbf{T}\overline{a} = 0$ is a linear combination of these $v_i$. I will again trust you to find a linear combination of these that's positive.

If your system is too big to do by hand, or if you want to automate this process, this is a very common example of a "[Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)" problem. If you learn enough to phrase your problem in this language (which won't be hard) there are many automated (and extremely fast!) LP solvers available in languages like Mathematica, Maple, and Sage.

**Edit:** I just noticed you want $a_i > 0$ - if you're OK with $a_i \geq 0$, 
then the LP approach can work. If you really want $a_i > 0$, though, LP is the wrong tool for the job.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I am sorry, but how do you know such positive solution exists? I mean I know how I can solve the problem given a particular case, but I am more interested in proving that the solution always exists.

Comment: Remember your assumption on halfplanes - Start with the $k=3$ case because it's easy to visualize. If all 3 points are above the x-axis, then you can't possibly decrease the x-coordinate without a negative coefficient. Conversely, if you have at least one point above and one point below the x-axis, then you can always shift the third point up _and_ down using only positive coefficients. Similar arguments can be made for the y-axis.